# python error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

here is my code

```
a = StringVar()
withdraw = Button(window, text="withdraw", width=10, height=3, bg='white', fg='navy blue',command=lambda: w()).place(x=550, y=400)
WITHDRAWinput = Entry(window, width=20, fg='navy blue', bg='white', textvariable=a).place(x=550, y=390)
wi = a.get()
wii = int(wi)

def w():
    x - wii
    j.set(x)
```

whats wrong?

Comment: `x - wii` doesn't do anything at all, you're calculating something but then not assigning the result anywhere. Did you mean something like `x = x - wii`?

Comment: you're calling `a.get()` about a millisecond after creating the widget. The user won't have even seen the widget, much less have a chance to type in it.

Comment: I think you just need to call `j.set(int(a.get()))` inside `w()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the button to be pressed before getting your Entry value.

Otherwise, `a.get()` is executed before the GUI is fully displayed, and thus an empty string

```
withdraw = Button(... , command=w)

def w():
    wi = a.get()
    wii = int(wi)
    x - wii  # not clear what you want to happen here, but this does nothing itself
    j.set(x)
```

Also,  `j` is not defined anywhere

Comment: its actually defined but i did not included

Comment: i actually want to build a banking system and this function is for withdrawing money and a is the user input that i made using tkinter

Comment: Alright. Not sure that information is needed for solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

`a.get()` returns an empty string (the default value of `StringVar`). Simplified, your code related to the error is:

```
a = StringVar()
wi = a.get()
wii = int(wi)
```

which is a long way to spell `int('')`, which results in the error you see. You need to defer grabbing and parsing the value from `a` until the `Entry` has been populated (at the very least until `w` is called in the code given, and even then you'd need to handle exceptions when the user provided invalid input).

Comment: but im using tkinter which i want to get the "a" from the entry

Comment: @jadplaymaker10 you're not waiting for the input though, you set up the entry and then immediately try to get a value from it. I'm not that familiar with tkinter though, does setting up the entry automatically wait until the value is gotten?

Comment: I'm not sure your code is equivalent, since `a` is passed to `Entry` and is mutable.  We don't expect `Entry` to modify `a`, but it certainly could in general.  Shouldn't the call to `Entry` be represented by your code?

Comment: @Steve: The `Entry` modifies its `textvariable` in response to input, but given the OP hasn't gotten around to executing the `tkinter` event loop, it impossible for it to have actually been interacted with, even if the user had infinite speed UI interaction, so it's irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @RandomDavis: no, tkinter doesn't automatically wait when you call `.get()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I understand what you're saying.  I was just wondering if the involvement of `a` in that additional call might mean that your simplification isn't quite right. No biggie.